# Python objects to JSON to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json

I've got a problem when trying to insert a json, which was converted from a python object with json.dumps, into a MySQL database. The connection to the database is working with another python file. I've already tried to just insert values, which was working, but with the json file it's not working.
My Python file:

```
import json
import dbConnection

cur = dbConnection.cursor
cnx = dbConnection.conn

DEVICES = {
        "id": "1",
        "isPoweredOn": "True",
    "os": "Linux"
}

j = json.dumps(DEVICES)
print(j)

sql = "INSERT INTO DEVICES (id, isPoweredOn, os) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"


val = (json.dumps(DEVICES))


cur.execute(sql, val)
cnx.commit()
print(cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Error code I get, when trying to execute:

```
"id": "1", "isPoweredOn": "True", "os": "Linux"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbInit.py", line 22, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql, val)
  File "/home/silvan/.virtualenvs/pyproj1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/silvan/.virtualenvs/pyproj1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/silvan/.virtualenvs/pyproj1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at line 1
```

My CREATE TABLE code:

```
CREATE TABLE DEVICES(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, isPoweredOn BOOLEAN NOT NULL, os VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If `os` is a `varchar` I think you should sorround it with sigle quotes (`(%s, %s, '%s')`). Also note that `True` may not work.

Comment: @dcg thanks, tried that, but still the same error. ```True``` is actually a boolean, I've tested it with %r an without any doublequotes in the python object. Without the json it works like this.

Comment: Don't insert val, do this instead: `cur.execute(sql, DEVICES)`.

Comment: @mvp Just tried that, unfortunately still the same error, I think I have to convert it from python to json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, cast the `DEVICES` to `dict`, then Here's the format.

`` sql = "INSERT INTO DEVICES (`id`, `isPoweredOn`, `os`) VALUES (%(id)s, %(isPoweredOn)s, %(os)s)" ``

Then Execute it :

```
try:
    cur.execute(sql, DEVICES)
    cnx.commit()
except error:
    print(error)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `json.loads(j)` and assign it to a variable, then you can access the values properly.

Try :

```
import json
import dbConnection

cur = dbConnection.cursor
cnx = dbConnection.conn


DEVICES = {
        "id": "1",
        "isPoweredOn": False ,
        "os": "Linux"
}
j = json.dumps(DEVICES)
values = json.loads(j) 
'''
# Quick debugging 
print(j , type(j))
print(values , type(values))
print(values['isPoweredOn'])
'''

sql = "INSERT INTO DEVICES (id, isPoweredOn, os) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

val = ( '' , values['isPoweredOn'] , values['os'])

cur.execute(sql, val)
cnx.commit()
print(cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Also since you defined `id` to be `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` it , you can't insert `device id` wich is `values['id']` to `id column`, you can alter `DEVICES table` and create a new column called `device_id` for storing the  `device id` if you need really need to store `values['id']`

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't properly work, but the solution above worked for me. Anyway, thanks for your input.